# QGIS vector edition corrupts SpatiaLite attribute table

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I have a problem with edit SpatiaLite Layer on QGIS.

When I make a this set of editions: cut line, delete a part, insert a new line and save it, the attribute table is corrupted.

I was thought that the trouble is within PK, but I have made new tests and now think the trouble is about value NULL in the numeric attributes of new features inserted. If I fill the atributes with any value when insert the trouble not occurs.

I tested it with a PK_UID attribute defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT and an spatial index on the geometry (type linestring). I also tested without PK.

I've tested on QGIS 2.2 and 2.4 (Windows 32).

Comment: I can verify the problem on 2.6 Win64. You must save right after splitting a feature. Only then can you continue editing.

Comment: @Micha this works, but in this case, the operation will be done by several people. I think that populate the attributes with a default value can solve. I will  try. Thanks very much.

Comment: Really. If numerical attributes receive some value (ie not null) there are no problems. In fact, it seems that there is a bug in the indices of attributes when a null occurs.

Comment: Moreover, it seems that there is something with the configuration of the form features. Hide some attributes the problem occurs.